# Odd data truncation upon import

Tags: mysql, flat-file, truncation, mysqlimport

Mysqlimport (and 'load data ...') are incorrectly importing data from my flat-file input.

The commands I've used to load are:

```
load data local infile '/srv/django/tmp/icdo_prev/orders_icdodiagnosis.csv' 
into table orders_icdodiagnosis 
character set latin1 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

or

```
mysqlimport -p -uroot --lines-terminated-by='\n' --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=',' --local -f -i <dbname> orders_icdodiagnosis.csv
```

Here are examples of what I'm seeing after import:

```
mysql> select code from orders_icdodiagnosis where id = 2311;
+---------+
| code    |
+---------+
 |9965/3
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select trim(code) from orders_icdodiagnosis where id = 2311;
+------------+
| trim(code) |
+------------+
    |5/3
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ltrim(code) from orders_icdodiagnosis where id = 2311;
+-------------+
| ltrim(code) |
+-------------+
     |/3
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

The input data is '9965/3', and is unquoted in the flat-file.  (If I use quotes in the flat-file, the quotes actually get entered as part of the data, ie '"9965/3"'.)

This looks like a line ending problem, but the data are truncated on the front side.  In the first example the display end lines are absent, so something is amiss, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Can anyone suggest a means of correcting the issue?

Thanks for any help you can supply.
Joe White

Have seen the same behavior with windows mysql and linux mysql.

Comment: Your file contains `\r\n` newlines, not `\n`.

Comment: Either fix the file with `dos2unix` or use `lines terminated by '\r\n'`

Comment: `select hex(code)...` can be useful for debugging this kind of thing

Comment: note that the quotes get actually entered as part of the data because it sees `"9965/3"\r`, which isn't "enclosed" by quotes since there isn't one at the end